# How can i switch this option menu on fragment to activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want this option menu on my add `apartment fragment` to `intent` here at the add apartment class. while running this code my app gets crashed, I might have missed something could someone please help me, what should I do??

LandlordAddApartment.java

```
public class LandlordAddApartment extends Fragment {

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

}
@Nullable
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {

    inflater.inflate(R.menu.add_apartment, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.landlord_add_apartment) {

            LanlordMapFragment mapFragment = new LanlordMapFragment();
            FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
            manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.landlord_apartment, mapFragment, mapFragment.getTag()).commit();

            return true;

    }




    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    getActivity().setTitle("Manage Apartment");
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.landlord_add_apartment, container, false);

    return v;
```

[image]

Comment: Please add your error output

Comment: Please add the menu.xml file contents too here. Also can you mention when does the app crash? On launch or when you click the option or when you try to expand the options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use from switching from `Fragment` to `Activity`:

```
startActivity(new Intent(getActivity,YourActivity.Class));
```

And while moving from `Activity` to `Fragment`:

```
YourFragment mapFragment = new YourFragment();
FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.landlord_apartment, mapFragment, mapFragment.getTag()).commit();
```